# SQL Server: trigger updating a just inserted row

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I currently working with an old application that I don't own any source code but I really need to add some new logic to the app.

The only way I found to do it is to mess up with database data, and change whatever I need with a trigger.

I wrote the following trigger that should update 2 columns of a just inserted row:

```
CREATE TRIGGER addLoteInfo ON fi
FOR INSERT
AS 
DECLARE
    @loteN          varchar(15),
    @refN           varchar(18),
    @CientifN               varchar(40),
    @CaptureZ       varchar(20)


    declare MY_CURSOR cursor for 
    select   
        i.lote, i.ref
    from inserted i

    open MY_CURSOR

    fetch next from MY_CURSORinto @loteN, @refN

    while @@fetch_status = 0  
    begin 

         SELECT @CientifN = u_ncientif FROM SE where lote LIKE @loteN and ref LIKE @refN;

         SELECT @CaptureZ = u_zcaptura FROM SE where lote LIKE @loteN and ref LIKE @refN;

        UPDATE FI SET LNCIENT=@CientifN, LZCAP=@CaptureZ;

        fetch next from CURSOR_TESTE into @loteN, @refN 

    end 

    close MY_CURSOR
    deallocate MY_CURSOR
```

The problem is when a new registry is inserted, it seems it gets to a deadlock.

Its impossible to do what I'm trying to do?

Can you help me with another approach?

Comment: Why update the just inserted rows instead of simply inserting the correct data to begin with?

Comment: the insert is made by the application, and i don't have access to his source code to change it, to include the 2 aditional fields.

Comment: Eww. Triggers + cursors + no app source code = recipe for pain. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `INSTEAD OF` trigger if you want to modify newly inserted/updated record on the fly.